# Removing old kernels

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, linux-kernel, aptitude

My boot partition is full and I can't install new kernel versions. So I tried to remove some old versions like this:

1. get active kernel

   uname -a

   Linux Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2. get installed kernels

   dpkg -l linux-image-* | grep ^ii

   output: http://pastebin.com/X9P81W22
3. now i try to remove linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic

   aptitude purge linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic

   output: http://pastebin.com/J4Zmhf9Y

I'm not shure because aptitude will delete linux-generic{a} and linux-image-generic{a} as well. Over 420MB will be freed. But my boot partition looks like this:

/dev/md1        488M  484M     0 100% /boot

is this normal??

Comment: Each kernel version comes as a set of packages. If you want to remove 3.13.0-24, remove all packages related to it (try `dpkg -l|grep 3.13.0-24` and look at all those starting with linux-, not just linux-image-)

Comment: Yes, I know and aptitude will delete dependencies as well (look at output #3). my problem is: aptitude will delete linux-generic{a} and linux-image-generic{a} and I don't know why because, in my opinion, this is necessary for the current kernel, or not?

Comment: Aptitude tells you that those generic packages are not completely configured (since last update failed due to lack of space). Trying to remove only a part of an old kernel just confuses things further.

Answer (score 1):

That seems normal to me.  For each kernel package, most of the kernel code (modules such as drivers) is stored in `/lib/modules/` (with some in `/lib/firmware/`).

On the other hand, the images in `/boot` require less than 10MB of disk space between them. The following lists the kernel image files for version 3.2.0-87 with sizes in kB.

```
4892    /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-87-generic
2836    /boot/System.map-3.2.0-87-generic
784     /boot/abi-3.2.0-87-generic
144     /boot/config-3.2.0-87-generic
```

#### Automatic removal of older / unused kernel packages

The following command is useful for automatically removing some (but not all) older / unused kernel packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

*Edit:* I noticed that you are currently using the `3.13.0-43-generic` kernel. It would be best to reboot the system to use the latest installed kernel, `3.13.0-55-generic`. The above command would be most effective if you are already using the most recently installed kernel.

Comment: First, apt-get autoremove didn't work for me because I had a broken update of the newest kernel (because of less disk space). So I tried to move some 20MB kernel images to backup folder and tried aptitude safe-upgrade again. After that I run apt-get autoremove sucessfully - thx.

Answer (score 0):

Askubuntu has questions (and answers) for that

- [Why aren't old linux-images removed when installing new kernel updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100733/why-arent-old-linux-images-removed-when-installing-new-kernel-updates)
- [How do I remove or hide old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)